# SQL procedure print cursor

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a sql procedure which has this declare statement for cursor

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR  SELECT count(value1), value1
FROM someDB.table1
INNER JOIN someDB.table2 ON table1.Id=table2.Id and 
A_code = input_code1;
AND B_code = input_code2
GROUP BY value1
  ORDER BY count(value1) desc
LIMIT 5;


OPEN cur1;
read_loop: LOOP 
FETCh cur1 INTO value2,value1;
set value = CONCAT(value2,' ',value1);

  select 'loop start';
  select value;
  -- for now, I'm just trying to print but here I'll have an insert statement 

 IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
```

the select statement does return values perfectly but when I'm trying to insert values in a table it says value1 cannot be null, the value is not null when I just run select statement not sure why this value is setting null in the cursor. Can someone help what I'm missing in this

Comment: you have to declare variables or use user variables a @value1

Comment: I didn't mention that here but I have declared everything, I think my main concern is with why the select statement is not setting values in the cursor?

Comment: You must add your complete procedure also we need to test it, your tables and some data with it. Or try to debug all your self, add a session variable and see what data you get after running the procedure You can SELECT @ a and see what you get.

Comment: Cool, let me try debugging with select @ :)

Comment: I got it, so the issue was the available name and column name were the same value1 was a column and one of the tables apparently MySQL had a conflict with that

Comment: Super good for you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I declared variable name for cursor same as a column name in the table,
So I started debugging and saw that the values for cursor were coming null, I started changing the name of variables and it fixed the issue. Look like MySQL has a conflict where variables name cannot be the same as a table column name.